# custom sudo command

Tags: macos, bash, virtualbox, boot-camp, sudo

How can I make custom functions accessible to the sudo command?

I have my Mac OS X set up with Bootcamp, but also with VirtualBox so I can run Windows for testing websites in IE. I have to run this sequence of commands to be able to boot Windows in VirtualBox:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/disk0s4
sudo chown myUserAccount bootcamp.vmdk bootcamp-pt.vmdk
sudo umount /Volumes/BOOTCAMP
VBoxManage list vms
VBoxManage startvm <uid>
```

It's a pain in the butt having to do this, so I'd like to automate it. I've created a file called **bootcamp.sh** in a personal development folder I keep. I have tried to include the following in several files:

```
. /Users/myUserAccount/Development/Bash/bootcamp.sh
```

I have tried including it in:

- My personal .bash_profile (not gonna work obviously)
- /etc/bashrc
- /private/etc/bashrc
- /private/etc/profile.

I have also tried to create a symlink in /usr/bin/ called bootcamp (without extension) and that worked partially, allowing me to do:

```
sudo sh bootcamp
```

But it still annoys me having to write *sh* in there. I tried including a shebang (#! /usr/bin/sh) in the top of the **bootcamp.sh** file, but without luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shebang is the correct path, then you just need to make the script executable to avoid needing the `sh`.

chmod +x /Users/myUserAccount/Development/Bash/bootcamp.sh

And provided `/Users/myUserAccount/Development/Bash/` is in the path, you can just do

```
sudo bootcamp.sh
```

You don't really need the .sh suffix either, you can rename it to just bootcamp.

The downside of this is that you will be running VBoxManage as root.  So I would put the commands

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/disk0s4
sudo chown myUserAccount bootcamp.vmdk bootcamp-pt.vmdk
sudo umount /Volumes/BOOTCAMP
VBoxManage list vms
VBoxManage startvm <uid>
```

into the bootcamp.sh file as they are.  Then run it as

```
bootcamp.sh
```

You'll be prompted for the first sudo to provide the password, but this means that the VBox commands will be run as a normal user.

Comment: Great, worked like a charm! If I'd just known about chmod +x <file>! Too I didn't consider just keeping the sudo's in the script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the file executable with

```
chmod +x bootcamp.sh
```

Also, you don't need sudo inside the script, if you use sudo to call the script.